# How to write cronjob for opencart?

Tags: php, cron, opencart, shopping-cart

I'm using opencart version 1.5.5.1 for our website. I need to write cronjob for a particular requirement. I'll be happy if I can use the already existing opencart functions by calling them from my script. Is there a way to do so? I researched on this, but couldn't find any answer.

I'm just curious to know if any such solution exists. Please share your knowledge. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "for a particular requirement" details!

Comment: Let it be for adding a 1000 categories from an excel file.

Comment: sigh, so you tried what?  the problem was what?

Comment: While running a cronjob the default opencart functions/files doesn't get loaded unlike we call functions via browser. So I've copied down the code and sql queries that already exists in other opencart files. I'm just curious to know if any solution exists to reuse the already existing opencart functions.

Comment: you can call a web page with a cronjob

Comment: Thanks! Need to check that.

Comment: That's possible, but is these any other method available to call other opencart functions from a php file/controller.